# counter-increment: is not working while i am print pdf using windows.print

Tags: javascript, printing, page-numbering

i am trying to print invoce
but it's showing me 1 page number to add pages

```
@media print
    {
  .footer {position: fixed; bottom: 10px;} 
  table { page-break-inside:auto }
  tr    { page-break-inside:auto;  }
  td    { page-break-inside: auto; }
  thead { display:table-header-group }
  tfoot { display:table-footer-group;  }
```

i want to add page number in invoice i have add this

```
.footer::after {
        counter-increment: page;  
        content: counter(page);  
    }
```